# How can I test for the size of the mint type at compile time?

Tags: librarylink

It is useful to know the size of LibraryLink's `mint` type at compile time, for interoperability with other libraries.  For example, should I use the `MLPutInteger32` or `MLPutInteger64` MathLink call to send a `mint`?

How can I find out the size of `mint` at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MINT_32` macro will be defined if `sizeof(mint) == 4` (i.e. if `mint` is 32-bit).  So simply use

```c
#ifdef MINT_32

...

#endif
```

It is the CCompilerDriver package that ensures that this macro is defined when necessary, by adding `-DMINT_32` to the compiler command.  If you compile manually, without using functions like [`CreateLibrary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateLibrary.html), it will be your responsibility to define it when appropriate.